# ASP .NET Core - Send uploaded file as multipart/form-data to API endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, api

From ASP .NET Core MVC I need to send request to API endpoint which requires **multipart/form-data** with the following format

```
{boundary value}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='file'; filename='filename.jpg'
Content-Type: image/jpeg

{file content}
--{boundary value}--
```

Within controller, I have uploaded the file as IFormFile interface which has properties:

```
Content-Type
ContentDisposition
```

How can I construct multipart/form-data and send it?

I've tried to use **MultipartFormDataContent** which has overloaded constructor with string boundary but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMultipart(string apiendpoint, byte[] data)
        {

            var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(); // your boundary value if need anything can be passed in the contructore
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType =
                MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");

            multipartContent.Add(fileContent, "file", "filename.jpg");
            //client is HttpClient static field in the class
            return await client.PostAsync(apiendpoint, multipartContent);
        }
```